# Magento 2: How do I enable or disable all modules (or subset) of a vendor in 1 command?

Tags: module, setup

Seeing we are installing, upgrading, removing a new M2 (2.3.1) install we wouldlike a fast way to enable or disable modules from vendors in 1 go. Either by the Vendor name or for a Subset of modules belonging to the same extension.

When extensions are acquired we see the following. One acquires 1 extension call it Foo_Coolstuff but it can then be packaged either as

- Foo_Core
- Foo_Coolstuff

Or as

- Foo_Core
- Foo_Coolsub1
- Foo_Coolsub2
- Foo_Coolstuff

To us as a user this is 1 extension. I mean this is how it is offered and how it is acquired.

Question: So how can we easily enable or disable for example (only)

- all modules from Vendor Foo_*
- or all modules from Extension Foo_Cool*

Answer (score 0):

One can use `magento module:status` to create lists of extensions. By wrapping this into `$()` it is executed first. It filters out the extensions that we want by using grep and adds a negative grep to be certain we dont match unwanted stuff.

**How to enable all modules from Vendor Foo_**

The base command to enable all modules from `Foo_` is like this

`php bin/magento module:enable $(php bin/magento module:status | grep '^Foo_' | grep -v '^List|^None|^Magento|^$')`

This will enable all Modules that start with the label `Foo_`.

**Changing you filter**

You can replace Foo with the Vendor name of your choice if the Modules label start with this string. Or you can remove the caret `^` and it will match anywhere in the string. Like this grep 'Foo' will match any extension that hass the string `Foo` in the label. Be carefull with this. A good way to test it is to first execute `php bin/magento module:status | grep '^Foo_' | grep -v '^List|^None|^Magento|^$'` and see the list that it returns: is this what you want?

**How to disable all modules from Vendor Foo_**

The same can be made to disable all modules from `Foo_`

`php bin/magento module:disable $(php bin/magento module:status | grep '^Foo_' | grep -v '^List|^None|^Magento|^$')`

**How to disable all modules from 1 certain extension called Foo_Coolstuff**

The same can be made to disable all modules and submodules from `Foo_Coolstuff`

`php bin/magento module:disable $(php bin/magento module:status | grep '^Foo_Cool' | grep -v '^List|^None|^Magento|^$')`

The above will enable all modules where the label starts with `^Foo_Cool`. Another option can be to add `^Foo_Core` then the command will become `grep '^Foo_Cool|^Foo_Core'`

Answer (score 0):

*it will find & disable all modules except which one start with Magento_*

```
$ php bin/magento module:status | grep -v Magento | grep -v List | grep -v None | grep -v -e '^$'| xargs php bin/magento module:disable
```

*To disable all module for particular vendor, you could use something like this*

```
$ php bin/magento module:status | grep VendorName_ | grep -v List | grep -v None | grep -v -e '^$'| xargs php bin/magento module:disable
```

The differences is one with grep -v Magento and the other is grep VendorName_

check this and let me know if any issue

Comment: use enable instead of disable for enabling module